# Why compiler complains about java.lang.Object on generic return type of method

Tags: java, generics

I'm trying to write a small internal DSL in Java which generates an tree of objects. The DSL code looks like this:

```
RuleBuilder builder = new RuleBuilder(new Syntax());
Syntax s =
builder.rule("rule1")
            .identifier("foo")
            .choice()
                .terminal("bar")
            .end() // 1) Here it works.
       .end() // 2) Here complains the compiler.
       .rule("rule2")
            .identifier("bar")
       .end()
       .build();
```

The compiler complains (at 2) that the object `java.lang.Object` returned by `end()` does not have a method `rule()`. It's obvious to me that Object does not have this method. The builder code is as follows (The code assembling the tree is left for simplicity):

```
class RuleBuilder {
    private final Syntax syntax;

    public RuleBuilder(Syntax syntax) {
        this.syntax = syntax;
    }

    public GenericBuilder<RuleBuilder> rule(String name) {
        return new GenericBuilder<RuleBuilder>(this);
    }

    public Syntax build() { return syntax; }
}

class GenericBuilder<P> {
    private final P parentBuilder;

    public GenericBuilder(P parentBuilder) {
        this.parentBuilder = parentBuilder;
    }

    public <P> P end() {
        return (P)parentBuilder;
    }

    public GenericBuilder<P> identifier(String value) { return this; }
    public GenericBuilder<P> terminal(String value) { return this; }
    public GenericBuilder<GenericBuilder> choice() { return new GenericBuilder<GenericBuilder>(this); }
    // ... other sub node types
}
```

The principal idea behind my implementation: The generated syntax tree consists of a Syntax root node which has some Rule nodes. This rule nodes can have some sub nodes. The sub nodes are of two types: Leafs and nodes (in the example code only choice for simplicity). I will provide a fluent interface where I can add nodes and leaves to the tree. To 'end' a tree branch there is the `end()` method which returns the parent builder.

The issue I try to solve is, that the method `end()` should return the parent builder object which may be of type `RuleBuilder` or `GenericBuilder`. I do not understand why it works at 1) and not at 2) in the example above.

I've read through a lot of resources about generics and I understand how `List<T>` and `Map<K,V>` and such works. And I'm aware of the "Erasure" thing, that the type information is lost at runtime. So I can understand that at runtime `end()` returns `java.lang.Object`, when type information is erased. But I got a compile time error. I've also read through the blog of Neal Gafter about Super Type Tokens and Typesafe Heterogenous Containers. But I'm not sure if this solves my problem. I tried several different approaches (during my search in the web), but now I'm stuck.

Comment: Jon has your answer.  But it would have been nice if you posted the error :)

Comment: The error is: Testcase: snafu(de.weltraumschaf.ebnf.ast.builder.SnafuTest): Caused an ERROR
Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.end.rule.identifier.end.build
java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - Erroneous sym type: java.lang.Object.end.rule.identifier.end.build
Testcase: snafu(de.weltraumschaf.ebnf.ast.builder.SnafuTest): Caused an ERROR
 at de.weltraumschaf.ebnf.ast.builder.SnafuTest.snafu(SnafuTest.java:45)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two problems. First there's this:

```
public GenericBuilder<GenericBuilder> choice() { 
    return new GenericBuilder<GenericBuilder>(this);
}
```

That's not saying what *kind* of `GenericBuilder` the "inner" one is. You should be able to change it to:

```
public GenericBuilder<GenericBuilder<P>> choice() { 
    return new GenericBuilder<GenericBuilder<P>>(this);
}
```

At that point, the inner `end()` call will still know it's got a `GenericBuilder<RuleBuilder>` instead of a raw `GenericBuilder`.

The second problem is here:

```
public <P> P end() {
    return (P)parentBuilder;
}
```

That's a generic method when it shouldn't be - you don't want to introduce a *new* type parameter `P` here; you just want the existing one:

```
public P end() {
    return parentBuilder;
}
```

Comment: +1 for being the fastest to spot the place where a generic class was instantiated without type parameters :-)

Comment: Jiha! Works! Thanks a lot Jon. The second problem (<P> in method return) came from some trial and error. I'm confused about this syntax. When or for what problem I should use this <P> P notation? I saw it in some code, but do not understand it.

Comment: @Weltraumschaf: You should use that when you want to declare a generic *method* - i.e. a new method which introduces another type parameter.

Comment: Do I understand right: The <T> T at method return type, the <T> is used if it is a type paramaeter which does not occure in the class/interface parameters? I saw an example where a static method uses <T> T, because there is no class instance which will have a type parameter?

Comment: @Weltraumschaf: There are two separate parts here: `<T>` just indicates that it's a generic method introducing a type parameter called `T`. That's *not* part of the return type - it's just specified before the return type. As it happens, the return type itself is `T` here.

Comment: @Jon Ok, I understand so far. But what I don't understand: In a class like `Foo<T>` T is specified when I say `Foo<Bar> f = new Foo<Bar>()`. But where do I specify the <T> for a method?

Comment: @Weltraumschaf: When you call it, you mean? It's somewhat non-obvious... something like `x.<String>y()`. I strongly suggest reading generics tutorials or the Java Generics FAQ at this point :)

Comment: @Jon: Crazy syntax, I've not seen this, yet. I've just bought Bloch's Effective Java :) Thanks for ypur help.